# How to print "org.hibernate.QueryException could not resolve property" in local server logs

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, exception

I see these exception

> org.hibernate.queryexception could not resolve property

in **Dynatrace** exception logs thrown from a specific Hibernate query fired through an action performed. I am trying to replicate this error in my local workspace (Eclipse Mars with Websphere 8.5) in order to debug and fix this issue but I don't get this error in my server logs. I have made `hibernate.show_sql = true` in **hibernate.cfg.xml**, but this only prints the HQL statements. Is there some other properties that I would have to set in order see this exception in my server logs?

Answer (score 0):

Dynatrace will also capture Exceptions that dont make it to your log files as Dynatrace captures Exceptions when Exception objects are created and not when they are logged to disk. This is why you typically see more Exceptions in Dynatrace than in log files.

What you could do is to use Dynatrace on your local workstation. There is a free for life version for local workstations - https://www.dynatrace.com/en/products/dynatrace-personal-license.html?utm_medium=blog&utm_source=dynatrace&utm_campaign=devops&utm_term=agrabner

Andi